# Redirected from Detection

Tags: iis

So, say I'm on `www.example.com`. And on that website, there's a link that goes to `my.domain.com`. I'm using IIS and I'm wondering if there's a way that the server detects that the user got to my website through `www.example.com`. Is there a module I can install or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most well-behaved webbrowsers sent a [`Referer Header`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) with URL that provided the link when they request a resource.

You can configure IIS to log the referer headers. For instance the default W3C Log format includes the Referer header.